# Does this method of computing all possible prefixes of a list run in O(n)?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, big-o

Consider the following function from [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#inits) which computes all prefixes of a list in the following way:

```
inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits = map toListSB . scanl' snocSB emptySB
```

This relies on some data structure referred to as the snocBuilder, implemented as follows:

```
data SnocBuilder a = SnocBuilder {-# UNPACK #-} !Word [a] [a]

{-# INLINE sb #-}
sb :: Word -> [a] -> [a] -> SnocBuilder a
sb lp f r
  | lp < 255 || (lp .&. (lp + 1)) /= 0 = SnocBuilder lp f r
  | otherwise                          = SnocBuilder lp (f ++ reverse r) []

-- The empty builder

emptySB :: SnocBuilder a
emptySB = SnocBuilder 0 [] []

-- Add an element to the end of a queue.

snocSB :: SnocBuilder a -> a -> SnocBuilder a
snocSB (SnocBuilder lp f r) x = sb (lp + 1) f (x:r)

-- Convert a builder to a list

toListSB :: SnocBuilder a -> [a]
toListSB (SnocBuilder _ f r) = f ++ reverse r
```

The comment above this snippet reads like this:

```
{- A "SnocBuilder" is a version of Chris Okasaki's banker's queue that supports
toListSB instead of uncons. In single-threaded use, its performance
characteristics are similar to John Hughes's functional difference lists, but
likely somewhat worse. In heavily persistent settings, however, it does much
better, because it takes advantage of sharing. The banker's queue guarantees
(amortized) O(1) snoc and O(1) uncons, meaning that we can think of toListSB as
an O(1) conversion to a list-like structure a constant factor slower than
normal lists--we pay the O(n) cost incrementally as we consume the list. Using
functional difference lists, on the other hand, we would have to pay the whole
cost up front for each output list. -}
```

But as I understand this, although `snocSB` runs in O(1) amortised, `toListSB` runs in O(n). This is because the right list has to be reversed anyway.

This should mean that the `inits` function takes O(n^2) time as opposed to the optimal O(n). Is this correct? What is a better way to implement inits?

Comment: I don't understand "the optimal O(n)". How can `inits` run in linear time?

Comment: Consuming `inits [1..n]` will always take `O(n²)` since there are n²/2 elements in the lists. You cannot do better.

Comment: @Bergi There are only O(n) prefixes for a given list.

Comment: @chepner but each of the prefix lists contains `O(n)` elements. Of course, if you just count prefixes (`length . inits`), `map x . scanl y z` will always run in `O(n)` regardless what `x`, `y` and `z` are because they're never evaluated.

Comment: Right; actually running `inits` doesn't require you to actually do that. The list of prefixes can be built in O(n) time, and the cost of building an individual prefix is combined with the cost to iterate over it.

Comment: Even worse, `inits` will always use O(n^2) memory if fully evaluated.  This is in contrast to `tails`, which will only use O(n) memory when fully evaluated.  This is just the nature of singly-linked immutable lists.